# Django debug=False but shows debug messages

Tags: python, django

I have set DEBUG=False in my production setup and yet it prints debug log messages

```
hostname=socket.gethostname()
Prod='prod-1'
if (hostname==Prod):
    DEBUG = False`
```

When I run somthing I can confirm DEBUG is set to False (Through a print message) but still the log.debug("Test") message gets printed

```
DEBUG is set to False
DEBUG is of <class 'bool'>
[16/Jun/2020 11:02:30] [DEBUG] [Main -> Test.py -> runTest -> 5 -> test]
```

Comment: Are you literally doing `if (hostname==Prod)`? `Prod` is a variable here, not a string. Also, what is `hostname`?

Comment: I updated with the missing code

Comment: @DhanushkaAmarakoon What file are you sending this log message from?

Comment: Do you have a `LOGGING` section in your `settings` module?

Comment: @Chris, Yes I do. I can confirm that the system worked find before. Meaning debug log messages were disabled in production via the DEBUG=False variable. Its just that after a update to the system and a restart this started to happen.

Comment: @ArunT Its from test file. Test.py running a function named runTest

Comment: "after a update to the system and a restart this started to happen"—what kind of update? Did your hostname change? Is `socket.gethostname()` still returning `prod-1`?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply I was unwell. The update was a minor code change not related to this, And then I restarted the uwsgi service. That's all.